# A crash caused by the OMP private parameter

Tags: fortran, openmp

When I use omp in my test fortran code, I find a strange problem. Following is the simple code

```
program Console1

use omp_lib

implicit none

complex, allocatable :: fft_image(:,:,:), temp(:,:)
real, allocatable :: intensity(:,:)
integer :: nx,ny,nz,i,j,k
nx=10;ny=10;nz=10;
allocate (fft_image(nx,ny,nz),temp(nx,ny),intensity(nx,ny))
fft_image=1
temp=0
!$OMP PARALLEL DO private(temp,k),REDUCTION(+: intensity),SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC) 
do k=1,nz
    temp=fft_image(1:nx,1:ny,k)

    call fft2d_mkl(temp,nx,ny,1)
    intensity=intensity+abs(temp)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

pause

end program Console1
```

If I set "temp" as a PRIVATE parameter, the program crashes with the information
[image]

However, if I delete temp from the private list, it runs. Obviously it is not the result I wanted.
I do not find the reason.

Comment: Please put the error message in the question. I will not click on links which lead lord know where. This is security 101

Comment: Do not use pictures for error messages, it is absolutely necessary to copy and paste it here **as text**. It must be searchable by people with a similar problem. See How to Ask.

Comment: Other questions - does it work without the openmp flags on the compiler line? What is the compiler and its version? And please tell us exactly what flags you are using on the compile line. I would need to check both the omp standards document but if temp is private the code looks valid fortran2003 and later, but not before that. And please turn that picture into text so it is searchable.

Comment: The error message is:"Debug Error! Program: ........console1.exe  Damage before 0x000000023009E820 which was allocated by aligned routine" I use ivf XE2011. If I do not use OMP, everything runs well.There are no problems during the compile if use or not use the OMP. The error  occurs only when running the program.

Comment: Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Take a look at `OMP_STACKSIZE`. You may benefit from setting it to a large-enough value.

Comment: How to change the OMP_STACKSIZE in ivf envrionment?

Comment: please tell us exactly what flags you are using on the compile line

Comment: I use Parallel Studio XE20011 with vs 2010. The environment setting are "/nologo /debug:full /O3 /Qparallel /assume:buffered_io /Qopt-matmul /Qopenmp /warn:interfaces /module:"x64\Debug\\" /object:"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc100.pdb" /traceback /check:bounds /libs:static /threads /dbglibs /Qmkl:parallel /c" for Fortran.

Comment: and "/OUT:"x64\Debug\Console1.exe" /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"D:\test\Console1\Console1\x64\Debug\Console1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:\test\Console1\Console1\x64\Debug\Console1.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /HEAP:999999999,999999999 /STACK:999999999,999999999 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /IMPLIB:"D:\test\Console1\Console1\x64\Debug\Console1.lib" for linker.